# dimension of a shape on sphere

Tags: spheres

I want to design soccer ball panels in solidworks software .
I want to know dimension of a shape on sphere (like length and width) and i know sphere radius.
For example i want to know dimesion of the surface in attachment picture.in this picture a sphere surface divide to six equal pieces and i dont know dimension of this.(diameter is 220mm)

[image: THIS SHAPE]

Comment: define what you mean by dimension? do you mean surface area, how to construct the plates, or the dimensions of the object in a 3D Cartesian grid?

Comment: i want to spread this curve on a plate with its dimension but i havent its dimensions.